# Hosting MS Access forms on SQL Server & SharePoint via browser

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

I have some data in two related tables on SQL Server. I want to do the following with minimal technical effort (and competence!!)

a) create a simple form to filter on attributes (standard filters avbl in MS Access) and display results in a simple table. Is there any built-in forms for this purpose- If I have a 80% ready form, I can probably tweak for the last 20%

b) instead of distributing the MS Access front-end file, is there a way to host it on SharePoint and access via browser

Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq-tDuPfgZc

Comment: thanks... this seems to handle (b). Any thoughts for (a)- built in search-and display forms?